# proof involving a series knowing that $a_n \rightarrow 2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose we know that $a_n \rightarrow 2$ determine whether the following series converges:
>
> $$ \sum \frac{1}{(a_n )^{2/n}} $$

We know that since $a_n$ converges, it is bounded, suppose for some index $n_0$ we have that $1<a_n <3$, since $a_n$ must converge to $2$ eventually, this is certainly true.

We can then say that $$ \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{1}{(a_n )^{2/n}} >  \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3 )^{2/n}}=\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{1}{(9 )^{1/n}}$$
The limit of the genreal term goes as $9^{-\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow 9^{0}=1>0$ So the minorant series diverges and the limit diverges.

Is my proof correct? Is there a quicker method to see this, perhaps?

Comment: I feel like this is a fine proof, and is about as short as one could ask for.

Comment: Yep. Basically if a series converges the summands must tend to zero. They do not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slightly shorter proof:
$$\log\biggl(\frac1{(a_n)^{2/n}}\biggr)=-\underbrace{\frac2n}_{\begin{matrix}\downarrow \\ 0\end{matrix}}\,\underbrace{\log(a_n)}_{\begin{matrix}\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}\downarrow \\ \log 2\end{matrix}}$$
so the denominator tends to $1$.

Comment: thanks, that is a nice proof.

Comment: I like how you used the braces.